# Applescript detect key press by user alternatives on MAC

Tags: macos, applescript

I have searched and found that Applescript is unable to detect key presses by user. I would like to know is there any other alternatives to do this?

I am building a script for a specific tabs in all internet browser, IE, FF, Chrome, Safari.

1) The specific tab will be blur out, title tab, favicon, URL in address bar will be masked or replace.

2) When the user press "tab" key for example, it will temporary remove all the things that is done in step 1.

3) If the user press tab again, it will go back to the state in step 1.

I have only managed to temporary make the body blur out but not the rest of step 1 and the detecting of key press.

Below is my code :

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set allTabs to front window's tab
    repeat with eachTabs from 1 to count of allTabs
        set eachTab to item eachTabs of allTabs
        if URL of eachTab = "https://web.whatsapp.com/" then
            set currentTab to eachTabs
        end if
    end repeat
    tell front window
        tell tab currentTab
            execute javascript "document.body.style.filter = 'blur(0)'"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I am completely new to this and it's my first time doing this.

Hope you guys can help me out with this. =(

Thanks in advance guys!